# Frege alluded to a logic algorithm?

Tags: mathematical-logic, computer-science, computation, algorithm

Somewhere (I wish I remember where) I read that [Gottlob Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/), although he didn't invent a logic algorithm, alluded to one (the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)? something else? converting truth tables to Boolean expressions in a normal form?).

Did Frege have an early idea regarding a logic algorithm, even though he did not invent an algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by "logic algorithm"?

Comment: @Nagase something that would fit in the same class of algorithms as the Quine-McCluskey algorithm